# transparent viewcontroller still showing a gosh image

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

Team, I have a navigation bar set up to be transparent but I am still getting a "ghost" image during the transition. Am I missing a property that needs to be set to clear?

code to make view controller transparent:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Here is before the transition: 
[BeforeImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo2XG.jpg)

During the transition:
[DuringImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7z1Z.jpg)

After the transition:
[AfterImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqzSu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For my app, I did this in `viewWillAppear`:

```
     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
     }
```

Mine doesn't have a little ghost flash in there, so maybe this will help. Looks like you just need to add the backgroundColor. Try it out and let me know.